# Can't create a file/directories in Ubuntu 11.10 even if rights are set correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.10, user-management

I'm affraid about something in ubuntu 11.10. I'm trying to give the write permission to the current user in a specific folder.
So, at first, I'm cnanging the owner to give the propriety to my apache user on the default folder (/var/www).

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www
```

Then, I add my current use into the group apache.

```
sudo usermod -a -G apache ollie314
```

I check that the ollie314 has the correct rights :

```
groups ollie314
> ollie314 apache
```

OK !
Now I check who am I.

```
whoami
> ollie314
```

Sounds good ...

```
cd /var/www
mkdir test
> mkdir: cannot create directory `test': Permission denied
```

hum ...
I made something wrong, but I don't know where. I suspect a pass through parent forlder issue but it works fine on my debian squeeze.
Somebody can help me ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I believe these changes take effect the next login.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Why would you need to log in again? The ACL on disk is updated (chown command) and the correct user is used. At most it might require a new shell with updated GID.

Comment: If it's not related to permissions on the group level, check if SELinux is active. Typically the possibilities to create new files and directories are pretty limited by default in the WWW root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Group changes like that don't take effect until the next time you log in. Log out then log back in.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
sudo mkdir test
```

THough it's not specified in the question weither or not you have acces to super user..